# extract the information from array key and update the objects of the arrays in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Explanation**: extract the information from the `info` Array `k`  key and update the array with extracted information from `k`. check the output document.

The logic for `info` is:

```
       "info":{ 
        "$filter" : {
             "input" : "$info",
             "as" : "p",
             "cond" : {
                "$and" : [
                   { "$ne" : [ "$$p.v", "-" ] }
                ]
             }
          }
      }
```

Document 1:

```
{
"info": [
    {
      "k": "2_3_4",
      "v": 0
    },
    {
      "k": "254_0_2",
      "v": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
"info": [
    {
      "A": 2,
      "B": 3,
      "C": 4,
      "k": "2_3_4",
      "v": 0
    },
    {
      "A" :24,
      "B" :2,
      "C": "NA",
      "k": "24_2",
      "v": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: no object can be that structure, object have keys and values `obj = {a:b,c:d}`, what do you mean?

Comment: Thanks for asking the question I just update the output. I forget to mention.

Comment: You can't have the same key on an object.

Comment: Yeah, as mentioned previously, that's not a good shape for an object. At best you won't have access to two of the three key-value pairs. At worst, you won't be able to create an object like this.

Comment: yes, I agree with your comments. I update my question with the expected output.  thanks for participating to give me the right direction.

Comment: What is the logic for `{"k": "254_0_2"} -> { "A": 24, "B": 2, "C": "NA" }` ?

Comment: I update my question with logic for `info` array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$map` to iterate loop of `info` array
- `$split` to split `k` string by "_"
- `$arrayElemAt` to get specific element from above result array from split
- `$ifNull` to check return result from the above operation is null then return "NA"
- `$let` to declare a variable `k` to store split result and process operator for "A", "B" and "C" in `in`
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object of `info` object and updated new properties object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      info: {
        $map: {
          input: "$info",
          as: "i",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$i",
              {
                $let: {
                  vars: {
                    k: { $split: ["$$i.k", "_"] }
                  },
                  in: {
                    A: {
                      $ifNull: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$$k", 0] }, "NA"]
                    },
                    B: {
                      $ifNull: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$$k", 1] }, "NA"]
                    },
                    C: {
                      $ifNull: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$$k", 2] }, "NA"]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9_MpksghwG8)